# Get Spring @Value from groovy script

Tags: java, spring, groovy

Inside Java code:

```
@Value("${myVar}") private String myVar;
```

Inside Groovy code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import groovy.transform.Field;
@Field @Value('${myVar}') String myVar;
return myVar;
```

returns null.

How to get `myVar` from Groovy script, assuming the `Beans` and `myVar` are not passed in?

Comment: Could you please show the full extend of the groovy script? There should be no reason, why you would not be able to annotate like this with a groovy class; unless you are really talking about a plain script (which then i have my doubts how that would work anyway), but have you tried annotating also with `@Field`?

Comment: it is a plain script.

Comment: Can you give a sample of what it is supposed to look like?

Comment: `@Field @Value ...` - but please provide a full failing example. I'd be interrested, how you run this groovy script so the spring context can take care of it.

Comment: just plain script, im new at groovy, doing some testing code. i've updated the code.

Comment: Have you tried using `@Field`? How do you use that with spring?

Comment: putting `@groovy.transform.Field @Value public void myVar` in groovy returns null, but that property was defined and the property is active in Spring.

Comment: You are evading my question of how spring and your script is related. In what do you think spring would inject that value for you?

Comment: I was reading and saw that this is possible. So I'm checking how to get the Spring @Value from groovy.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't do that. In order for Spring to inject a value, the enclosing class has to be managed by Spring. A Groovy script is not managed by Spring. You can still use Groovy, but you have to put the field in a Groovy class and make it a Spring bean, just as you would in Java. If you really want to, you can still bootstrap it from a Groovy script, instead of a "static void main" method, but I don't see the point of that.

Comment: @BjørnVester so, how do I make a Groovy class a Spring Bean?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want Spring context to be available during your Groovy script execution and perform the usual injection on your script properties.

Groovy scripts are compiled to Groovy classes, and so you should be able to simply use `beanFactory.autowireBean(this)`. However, to obtain a reference to a `BeanFactory` in the first place, you need to manually start a Spring context like so:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext('path/to/applicationContext.xml').withCloseable { context ->

    context.autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(this)
    ... //the rest of your script goes here
}
```

(You might need to adjust the `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("path/to/applicationContext.xml")` part to suit your needs, depending on what method you prefer to use to bootstrap your Spring context; also, if the script is part of a larger codebase, you might want to craft a smaller application context than for the rest of the app, to save startup time and avoid the usual side effects. Depends on the use case, though).

The only part I'm unsure of is whether `@Field` retains the original annotations when transforming a variable to a field, but if you're not getting any errors, I would assume that to be the case.

In case annotations are not retained, you can always declare a simple annotated POJO bean acting as a container for the injectable properties and call `def myPojo = new Pojo(); context.getBeanFactory()).autowireBean(myPojo)` instead.

Comment: with the Pojo `public class MyClass{@Value("${myVar}") private String myVar;public String getMyVar(){return myVar;}}` after I do `autowireBean` or `initializeBean`, the `getMyVar` still returns null. There are no Spring errors so I assume that the xml and properties files are ok. Anything I missed out?

Comment: Not sure without seeing the project setup. Is the sourse for the `myVar` property present on the script's classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the groovy script is managed by spring, you can either add the @Service or @Component annotations on the class. see example below

```
@Service
class Demo {

  public @Value('${valueA}') String valueA

  String showValue() {
    return valueA
  }

}
```